# Creating C++ window forms in a text editor

Tags: c++

Im begining a bold new step in application development, c++ and I have not been able to find any decent documentation on coding form windows in a text editor without gui/ides like visual studio.

Even though I have no Cpp background If I had a working example of a form window in pure .h(cpp header) and .cpp(cpp source) for a form window and a login form that uses mysql connector for user credential authentication, I will be able to use this as a starting point, or baseline for my first Cpp application. My abilities with programming languages is similar to a pianist that doesn't read music but plays by ear, although I can learn to read music by listening to it if that makes sense. Basically if someone can point me in the right direction of creating form windows and login forms with mysql databases I can pickup from there without any help as I can learn from reading it. Many thanks in advance if you know what I'm after.

:)

Comment: Although I have noticed some similarities to PHP/PDOExtention in the cpp syntax, it has proven a pain to make sense of without examples of form windows written by user and not a wizard, on top of this no wizard makes mysql/cpp forms anyway. So it's not that the syntax is out of my comfort zone but the fact that PHP/PDO doesn't write OS'es and OS applications so I have no baseline in regards to make form windows.

Answer (score 2):

Each operating system (Windows, Linux, Mac, etc.) has its on set of API's to create windows in C++. However coding purely from C++ and using only those API's can bit a little bit tedious and time consuming so there are several frameworks that simplify using those API's.

It can also make you application only compatible with one OS.

Visual Studio comes with MFC, that is only compatible with Windows, and not so great in my opinion.

The best up to date, cross-platforms frameworks are in my opinion Qt, wxWidgets, GTK+.

There's a list of them there:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_platform-independent_GUI_libraries

In my opinion the best free framework at the moment, compatible with several OS (Windows, Linux, MAC, Android, iOS, etc.) with the best documentation is Qt.

https://www.qt.io/download/

Download this framework, and develop with QtCreator and you won't regret it.

You could still develop with Visual Studio and Qt, however QtCreator makes the Qt integration easier, and has a better text editor out of the box. Also it has GUI editor that makes creating forms much easier.

Qt also supports several databases, and has a driver for MySQL, as many others as you can see on this page:

http://doc.qt.io/qt-5.4/sql-driver.html

Comment: Thanks for this, it has resolved my dilemma regarding lack of gcc c++ documentation for raw code, and so I my thought to be unmentioned cross compatibility concern.

Comment: On a personal note I have never had much luck with drag_n_drop IDEs, but have always prospered in coding the same thing in notepad, sounds daft but it is very frustrating as getting something that should otherwise be easier to fail and the more complicated thrive so I've avoided DnD. It seems quite backwards if you ask me.

Comment: you're not obliged to use the GUI editor for your project, you can code all by hand if you want. QtCreator is compatible with Visual C++ and gcc, whereas Visual Studio is only Visual C++. On complex projects, code completion of QtCreator is a must.